# NSPopUpButton drawRect handle pushed

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I subclass NSPopUpButton (which is placed in toolbar and opens an NSMenu) and do alternative drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   if (ISPUSHED) {

   } else {

   }

}
```

**How to determine if the button is pushed down (the menu is showing)?**

Answer (score 0):

`NSPopUpButton` is a subclass of `NSButton`, so you can override the `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:` methods just as you would on any other button.

If you need to, you can use them to set a Boolean property like `isPushed` and use that in your `drawRect:` method, but it would probably be smarter to put the drawing code in `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:`.

Comment: this doesn't work always as expected, when in combination with a menu that pops up

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe edit your question with the code that you're using? It would help to know your actual goal—are you trying to change the button image when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which worked in case of a NSPopUpButton with an NSMenu was setting it as the delegate

```
@interface AddDevicePopUpButton()

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isShowingMenu) BOOL showingMenu;

@end

@implementation AddDevicePopUpButton

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.menu.delegate = self;

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    if (self.showingMenu) {

    } else {

    }

}

- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    self.showingMenu = YES;
}

- (void)menuDidClose:(NSMenu *)menu {
    self.showingMenu = NO;
}
```